# Scala: do something if get the value in getOrElse

Tags: scala, collections, option-type

If a variable is an `Option[Account]`, and there is a string field called `accountName` in the class `Account`.

e.g:

```
val allAccounts: Set[Option[Account]] = Set(Some(Account1), Some(Account2), None)
```

How do I get the `accountName` from `Some(Account)` if I get something from getOrElse?

I tried `allAccounts.map(_.getOrElse("").accountName)` but it doesn't work. It cannot apply to the "get" part but the "OrElse" part

Thanks for your help!

PS: wonder why `allAccounts.map(_.map(_.accountName).getOrElse(""))` works fine with None value but if I create another variable: `val sampleAccount2 = None` and `sampleAccount2.map(_.accountName).getOrElse("")` will failed? Basically I just goes from `Set(None)` to `None` ?

Comment: `allAccounts.map(_.map(_.accountName).getOrElse(""))`

Comment: @XavierGuihot I would use `fold` in this case: `allAccounts.map(_.fold("")(_.accountName))`

Comment: Possibly, I just didn't want to add too much complexity, just the bare minimum to give an understanding of the issue

Comment: @Tim Why ? It is more opaque for beginners... and seems kind of unnacessary complication. It involves a totally unnacessary string creation as well. Is there a specific reason for your preference, or is it just personal taste ?

Comment: @sarveshseri I don't agree that it is more complicated, it is just different. It is also clearer and more efficient.

Comment: Ok. So... it is just personal taste. And less efficient due to extra string creation (and unncessary more complicated to me as a third party).

Comment: The Scala library is full of methods that can be implemented using combinations of other methods. I would argue that it makes them simpler rather than more complicated. Is `groupMapReduce` more complicated than `groupBy`/`map`/`reduce`? And, yes, `fold` is more efficient than `map`/`getOrElse` because it only tests the `Option` once (the `String` is only created if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you ultimately wanted to achieve?

```
final case class Account(accountName: String)

val allAccounts: Set[Option[Account]] =
  Set(Some(Account("Account1")), Some(Account("Account2")), None)

def getAccountNames(maybeAccounts: Set[Option[Account]]): Set[String] =
  maybeAccounts.map(_.fold("")(_.accountName))

assert(getAccountNames(allAccounts) == Set("Account1", "Account2", ""))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/R7fQV6U6RZqFL9UXS5CElQ/5).

Another way to write `getAccountNames` is by using a combination of `map` and `getOrElse` instead of `fold`, like so:

```
def getAccountNames(maybeAccounts: Set[Option[Account]]): Set[String] =
  maybeAccounts.map(_.map(_.accountName).getOrElse(""))
```

This is probably closer to what you initially wanted to write. In this case `fold` and `map` with `getOrElse` are basically equivalent, choose whichever makes more sense given your knowledge of the code base you're working on at the moment.

This version is also available [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/R7fQV6U6RZqFL9UXS5CElQ/6).

The problem with your attempt if that you were applying `getOrElse` to the `Option[Account]` type, meaning that you were trying to return something that was either an `Account` (within the `Option`) or a `String` and from that thing you were then asking the `accountName`, which only makes sense on `Account` but not on `String`. The key difference is that in this case you first `map` on `Option[Account]` to get the `accountName` on `Some`s, getting an `Option[String]`, *and then* you either get what's in there or the default value if the `Option` is empty.

---

As further input, please note that since you are using a `Set`, if you have multiple empty values in your input, they will be effectively collapsed into one, as in the following example:

```
assert(getAccountNames(Set(None, None)) == Set(""))
```

If by any chance you would rather remove any empty value entirely from the output, you can do so by rewriting the function above so that it's defined like so ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/R7fQV6U6RZqFL9UXS5CElQ/1)):

```
def getAccountNames(maybeAccounts: Set[Option[Account]]): Set[String] =
  maybeAccounts.flatMap(_.map(_.accountName))
```

In this case `getAccountNames` can be redefined in terms of a `for`-comprehension (more on the topic [here on the Scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html)):

```
def getAccountNames(maybeAccounts: Set[Option[Account]]): Set[String] =
  for {
    maybeAccount <- maybeAccounts
    account <- maybeAccount
  } yield account.accountName
```

This last example is also available [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/R7fQV6U6RZqFL9UXS5CElQ/2) for you to play around with it.

In both cases, the assertion that holds now changes to the following:

```
assert(getAccountNames(allAccounts) == Set("Account1", "Account2"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Wonder what if I want to iterate the set and have a map like this: Account (an instance) -> accountName

Comment: Another question is why if I create two examples below:

val sampleAccount1 = Some(Account("Account11"))
val sampleAccount2 = None

sampleAccount1.map(_.accountName) -> will return Some(Account11) instead of a string Acccount111? I thought when "map", it goes inside the Some()?
And sampleAccount1.map(_.accountName) will throw an error?  I think it is because the None has no map function, but why it works when in an iterable collection and with flatMap? (i.e. maybeAccounts.flatMap(_.map(_.accountName))), it will filter the None